# How to show the "new" gif image when a list's date column is equal to Today()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a list with column "Publish Date" and "Title". User want to attach a "new" gif image at the end of "content" if "Publish Date" for that row is equal to Today.

From my understanding, the OOB new indiciator follow the "Created date" only which do not fit our need.

Thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataview webpart from sharepoint designer and achieve this functionality.

Yes, there is no only configuration way to achieve this.

I think NEW image appearance configuration is of farm level. Hence it wont be a good idea to change this. You need someone with sharepoint designer skills.